# link django user to perticular site in site framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-sites

I've setup Django sites framework in my project,
actually, i want to combine Django user to that particular site

What I want to achieve is that when user register from particular site or subsite which register with site framework then that user has to link to that particular site so that we can restrict a user to login to another site with their associate site credential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the settings files for your different sites you can specify separate "users" databases, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/

```
#in site1 settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data_site1',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}

#in site2 settings.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'app_data',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    },
    'users': {
        'NAME': 'user_data_site2',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te'
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be good idea but there is one problem with that please refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/sites/

we bind model 
`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # ...
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`

so if we use different database for different site then there is no meaning of this because site table also changes for different site right

I need one database but differenciate user according site like above model using foreign key